# Why isn't equality in the triangle equality true when $x = y$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So for the triangle inequality, I say the equality holds if and only if $x = y$.

Proof:

$|x+y| = |x|+|y|$

$|x+x| = |x|+|x|$

$|2x| = 2|x|$

$|2x| = |2x|$

Q.E.D.

Why is this incorrect, and that the equality only holds true when both the signs are the same or one of the number equals $0$ ? Thanks.

Comment: What you proved is that if $x = y \implies |x+y| = |x|+|y|$. But $|x+y| = |x|+|y|$ does not imply $x = y$. For example, take $x=1$ and $y=2$.

Comment: What is the setting here? I'm guessing that this is real analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check $$|3+2|= |3|+|2|$$

The equality holds with $x$ and $y$  not being equal.

So it is not if and only if statement, but if $x=y$, then we have  $$|x+y|= |x|+|y|$$ as you have indicated.

Comment: Maybe it should say "The equality holds (in this case) with $x$ and $y$ being *unequal*."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think if you could add that $x = y$ is not reversible with the given steps, that would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

If these are real numbers and $|\cdot |$ is the usual absolute value, then
$$\begin{aligned}
& |x+y| = |x| + |y| \\
& \iff |x+y|^2 = (|x| + |y|)^2 \\
& \iff x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = x^2 + 2|xy| + y^2 \\
& \iff xy = |xy| \\
& \iff xy \geq 0
\end{aligned}$$
which holds if and only if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign or either is zero.